# Trigger transitions without javascript in CSS on page load

Tags: css, css-transitions

I would like to increase the width of a bar with a CSS transition but don't like to trigger it with a hover event ( like  http://jsfiddle.net/TFHn9/ )

I just would like to have an instant animation (when the page loads) - without Javascript of course.

Any chance to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Css3 keyframes: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/17/an-introduction-to-css3-keyframe-animations/

Comment: I knew them, but I need something for the Gecko/Presto/Trident machines

Comment: Mozilla needs the vendor prefix. Others don't look like they support it: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: I say use feature detection with plugins like modernizr and do the CSS keyframe for browsers that support it and then fallback to a JS version for those that don't.

Comment: Didn't find a solution without JS s I go with animations. Thanks!