# Changing div content on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a solution, in which div content changes on page load, randomly. Much like a JavaScript image on page load. I have made further notes in the code below.

I could do a randomize the content like images with JavaScript on page load, but here it's divs and I'm not sure how to change content inside them.

```
<div class="row BSlots">
    <div class="Grid_4 fl">
        /* This would be the code which would change */
        /* For example once it would be <div class="hello"><p>Hi</p></div> and the other <iframe="Link"/> */
    </div>
    <div class="Grid_4 fr">
        <script>Widget2(); /* Don't mind this, loading an actual JS image randomizer here */</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can this be achieved without using JS? If not, I'd appreciate a basic example which I could fiddle with :)

Comment: Without scripts, be it client-side or server-side, no way I think.

Comment: You can not do this without javascript. The only option you have is server-side, but after each page load it remains static.

Comment: @Daniel I think it's possible without JavaScript.

Comment: There are two scenarios. One is dynamically after page load. This will require javascript. A second is a random image in a variable that is loaded on server side. You will need a server side language like php, asp, jsp.

Comment: @Daniel What about something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995039/trigger-transitions-without-javascript-in-css-on-page-load ?

Comment: @Benjamin - Love the animation there :-) .. But the OP wants to put in content with text and tags and not specifically an image (which I did imply). I don't see the CSS transition is going to be helpful here. But thanks ... love it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it could be achieved without Javascript. It depends on which serverside-technology you use. You could create a template and insert serverside ransom image-tags.
It is possible too, to do it via javascript. 
If you want to use jQuery, you could do something like:

```
$(function(){
  $(".Grid_4 fl").html(generateRandomImageHtml());
});
```

Comment: Hi, please try to avoid using jQuery in questions that don't ask for it. Also, can you elaborate on how to do this with a server-side language without JavaScript? Thanks.